# How to find drivers breaking digital signature enforcement in Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7 wont start if i don't disable digital signature enforcement in boot load screen. So i would like to find drivers that cause this to consider removing them. I've read there are some ways to permanently disable digital signature enforcement, but since it seems like a security method i don't want to put my PC to the risk of unsigned drivers. So how to find drivers blocked by digital signature enforcement?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Autoruns from sysinternals to verify drivers

from [Using Autoruns to validate system drivers](http://blogs.technet.com/b/clinth/archive/2013/11/21/using-autoruns-to-validate-system-drivers.aspx)

> Validate drivers: This step checks non-Microsoft drivers. According to
>   the Windows Sysinternals Administrator’s Reference, “Verifying a
>   digital signature associated with that file gives a much higher degree
>   of assurance of the file’s authenticity and integrity.”  Note: When a
>   driver is verified, the Publisher field changes from the company name
>   to the name on the signed certificate.
>   1.Click the Drivers tab and look for drivers that are “Not Verified”. This will show up in the Publisher field.

and

> 3.If any of the drivers are highlighted and come up as “Not Verified” in the Publisher field, then the driver does not have a digital
>   signature.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for answer. I have a lots of red items with "Not Verified" info. Does it mean i should remove those entries so that Windows will start again? Normally i need to disable signature check to be able to run it. Here is a part list of my entries: http://polishwords.com.pl/blog/wp-content/screenshotUploads/2015-06-22_13-24-38.png

Comment: I would strongly advice against disabling device drivers at random. You will first have to determine your minimal set of drivers needed to boot in Safe Mode. (HKLM\CurrentControleSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal). I would try finding out if all my drivers in the minimal set are at least signed. If they are not, find an updated driver. There shouldn't be any reason why one of those shouldn't be signed.

Comment: Kersmaekers Thanks for help. I've tried sfc -scannow, but it tells me it can not repair files. I've did full chkdsk with no result. The problem with the thing you write is that i am unsure if i figure out how disabling certain  drivers influence software i have. I will try to do the windows upgrade. Maybe it will help

Comment: Does windows start in safe mode without disabling the enforcement? If it does, your minimal set of drivers are at least signed. If it doesn't, you have to figure out what driver is minimal required and not signed. If you walk the tree structure of the registry path I gave, look for "folders" with the value "Driver" in the Data column. The foldername is the drivername. On my system, vga.sys for example is a minimal required driver *(it should be on yours to)*

Comment: Thanks for tip, I will try it today since i would need 16 GB to upgrade Windows and i dont have it

Comment: I've tried boot in safe mode but also it hangs. I've disabled restart on errors and noticed this error: C000021a fatal system error: Session Manager failed to create protected prefixes 0xC0000031. I've also scanned disk and memory but they are ok. I've also did this: bcdedit -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON with no results.

Comment: Finally i repaired it by upgrading Windows in place. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better answer:
https://www.ghacks.net/2015/04/11/how-to-verify-that-system-drivers-are-digitally-signed/

- Open 'run' by pressing Windows + R keyboard
- Type `sigverif` and press enter
- Scan and see the results